# DataTables numerical sorting not working

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I initialize a table with the DataTable plugin with the following code:

```
                $('#data-table').dataTable( {
                "columnDefs": [
                    { "orderable": false, "targets": [0,1,4,5] },
                    { "type": "num", "targets": 3 }

                ]
            } );
```

I want to sort the elements in the third column numerically, but it doesn't work, if I remove the:

```
 { "type": "num", "targets": 3 }
```

The sorting works, but not numerically, it sorts: 191, 233, 28, 29 , 303.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems to work fine in isolation: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/zb45couf/. Check your console for errors. Also check that the `targets` setting matches your data.

Comment: Seems to be working fine in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/fen1x/pen/QxEXWw?editors=1010). Check your target index - it starts from 0.

Answer (score 0):

Add the **order** option to your initialization. It tells datatables how the columns should be sorted:

```js
$('#data-table').dataTable( {
    ...
    "order": [ 3, 'asc' ],
    ...
} );
```

https://datatables.net/reference/option/order